# How do I ensure an idempotent database insert with Entity Framework 5?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, azure-sql-database

I want to ensure that my database (SQL Server) updates are idempotent, similar in functionality to the blog post below, but using Entity Framework (v5, **Database First**):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2013/03/11/sql-database-connectivity-and-the-idempotency-issue.aspx

However, if I add an @Operation parameter to my insert proc, I get

> *"Error 2037: A mapping function bindings specifies a function ... but
>   does not map the following function parameters: Operation"*

(The @Operation would be a GUID, generated by the app, allowing the app to retry with the same GUID if it doesn't get a success response from the proc. The proc would write the GUID to a log table, and only perform the insert if the GUID doesn't exist - thus ensuring an idempotent transaction.)

Is there an elegant solution?

Comment: How do you map that parameter?

Comment: I'm using a Database First approach (edited the question to clarify); in the model editor's stored proc mapping window, I'm unable to edit the mapping of the @Operation property. So the answer to your comment is that I'm not (hence the error!).

Comment: Did you map the stored procedure to an insert operation of the entity? In such case your entity must have `Operation` property.

Comment: Yes, but the entity doesn't have an operation column - the parameter is additional. It's only there to allow the stored procedure to ensure the insert is idempotent. Is it possible to have a stored procedure mapped as an insert operation with more columns than the underlying entity?

Comment: No it is not possible.

Comment: Can you add more detail as to why you can't use a MERGE instead that would do nothing on match (IE no use of the "WHEN MATCHED" clause)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Release 6.1 of Entity Framework will solve this issue. (Thanks EF team - fabulous work.)

https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Handling%20of%20Transaction%20Commit%20Failures%20

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your query properly - How about applying a unique constraint on the column which holds the GUID and then if you don't get a success response back after EXECuting the proc, retry the insert.

Within the insert proc potentially use a try/catch or even query for the GUID value w/o Try/Catch and if it's there handle the exception or just exit the proc cleanly with a success message via the RETURN statement.

I don't think you'll need to do anything special on the EF side.

And one last thing, maybe wrap the CRUD insert/update statement inside a transaction to ensure that a value was in fact written like in the example provided.